# Resizing the Stage / Scene to fit the Window

Tags: java, javafx, resize, fxml

I am new in using JavaFX, and I am facing trouble fitting/sizing my application window.The program can be seen in the image shared below.
When I initially run my program, the size is too small and when i maximize it, the whole anchorpane floats to the left of the window as shown in second image.What I actually want to implement is shown in the third window.

[image: window1]

[image: window2]

[image: window3]

I want to start my app initially as it is shown in the 3rd image, and when the window is resized, the scene must also stretch fitting the stage.
I am very new to JavaFx, so please post help with some example so I can get my app working

Comment: The scene has always the same size as the stage. What you could do is adding another pane as root to the scene, that initially does not fill the whole space but only the needed one and then resize it.

Comment: So you want someone else coded that layout for you from the scratch.. sorry but that's not fair.. Firstly you should post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you read @UlukBiy ??? I said gimme just an example which is obvious in an answer.

Comment: Hey @Adil you can find examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/).

Comment: you are asking a question that's off scope (you can easily search for examples yourself - why ask?) and then you start offending the person pointing that fact out? incredible ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you did `Clean and Build` and then run the file